# restructuring large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a R data frame with the current structure, where there are +200 bins:

| GBO | Group | Index | bin1 | bin2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loc | 1 | DP | HoS | HeS | ... |
| loc | 1 | DPI | 0.1 | 0.02 | ... |
| loc | 1 | DPP | 0.3 | 0.1 | ... |
| loc | 2 | DP | DR | HoS | ... |
| loc | 2 | DPI | 0.0 | 0.2 | ... |
| loc | 2 | DPP | 0.2 | 0.01 | ... |

And I'm trying really hard to re-structure the df to look like this:

| GBO | Group | Bin | DP | DPI | DPP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loc | 1 | bin1 | HoS | 0.1 | 0.3 |
| loc | 1 | bin2 | HeS | 0.02 | 0.1 |
| loc | 2 | bin1 | DR | 0.0 | 0.2 |
| loc | 2 | bin2 | HoS | 0.2 | 0.01 |

My brain is melting and I'd really like some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `dcast` + `melt` from package `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(
    melt(setDT(df), id = c("GBO", "Group", "Index"), variable.name = "Bin"),
    GBO + Group + Bin ~ Index
)
```

which gives

```
   GBO Group  Bin  DP  DPI  DPP
1: loc     1 bin1 HoS  0.1  0.3
2: loc     1 bin2 HeS 0.02  0.1
3: loc     2 bin1  DR  0.0  0.2
4: loc     2 bin2 HoS  0.2 0.01
```

---

Or, you can use `recast` from package `reshape2`

```
> library(reshape2)

> recast(df, GBO + Group + variable ~ Index, id.var = c("GBO", "Group", "Index"))
  GBO Group variable  DP  DPI  DPP
1 loc     1     bin1 HoS  0.1  0.3
2 loc     1     bin2 HeS 0.02  0.1
3 loc     2     bin1  DR  0.0  0.2
4 loc     2     bin2 HoS  0.2 0.01
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(GBO = c("loc", "loc", "loc", "loc", "loc", "loc"
), Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Index = c("DP", "DPI",
"DPP", "DP", "DPI", "DPP"), bin1 = c("HoS", "0.1", "0.3", "DR",
"0.0", "0.2"), bin2 = c("HeS", "0.02", "0.1", "HoS", "0.2", "0.01"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 4):

A double `tidy` pivot - first `pivot_longer` then `pivot_wider` - should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(bin1:bin2, names_to = "Bin", values_to = "val") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Index, values_from = val)
```

Output:

```
#   GBO   Group Bin   DP    DPI   DPP  
#   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 loc       1 bin1  HoS   0.1   0.3  
# 2 loc       1 bin2  HeS   0.02  0.1  
# 3 loc       2 bin1  DR    0.0   0.2  
# 4 loc       2 bin2  HoS   0.2   0.01
```

Note: I selected all columns from `bin1` to `bin2` by simply specifying them (`bin1:bin2`) - you could replace `bin1:bin2` to something like `starts_with("bin")` if they weren't in order.

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "GBO    Group   Index   bin1    bin2    del
loc 1   DP  HoS HeS ...
loc 1   DPI 0.1 0.02    ...
loc 1   DPP 0.3 0.1 ...
loc 2   DP  DR  HoS ...
loc 2   DPI 0.0 0.2 ...
loc 2   DPP 0.2 0.01    ...", h = TRUE)
df <- df[,-grep("del", names(df))]
```